# Selenium Webdriver url keep returning to default "data:," after get(url) method

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jupyter, browser-automation

A few days before, my code for this website work perfectly:

```
url_TKLLPG_1 = 'https://truyenhdx.com/truyen/than-kiem-luu-lac-phap-gioi/chap/10323547-chuong-19/'
```

I used this to automatically refresh after 2 second interval and then find the next button and click on it:

```
def open_and_refresh_websiteVL(driver, url, interval_seconds, number_of_chapter = 0):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(6)
        time.sleep(2)
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print(f'WebDriverException caught at {number_of_chapter}, url: {url}')
        driver.quit()
        new_driver = get_chrome_driver()
        open_and_refresh_websiteVL(new_driver, url, interval_seconds, number_of_chapter)
    except WebDriverException:
        driver.quit()
        return
    count = 0
    while(count<=2):
        time.sleep(interval_seconds)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(interval_seconds)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(interval_seconds)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(interval_seconds)
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(interval_seconds)
        count+=1
    if(number_of_chapter > 80):
        driver.quit()
    if(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="html"]/body/div[5]/div/div/div[8]/div[3]/a')!=[]): 
        buttonNext = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="html"]/body/div[5]/div/div/div[8]/div[3]/a').click()
    nexturl = driver.current_url
    open_and_refresh_websiteVL(driver,nexturl, interval_seconds, number_of_chapter+1)
```

and here is my chrome options setting  (this is based on multiple research and solutions that I found online):

```
def get_chrome_driver():
    ua = UserAgent()
    user_agent = ua.random
    print(user_agent)
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # Adding argument to disable the AutomationControlled flag 
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") 
    # Exclude the collection of enable-automation switches 
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) 
    # Turn-off userAutomationExtension 
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False) 
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    return driver
```

This is how I called the function:

```
refresh_interval = 2
driver = get_chrome_driver()
open_and_refresh_websiteVL(driver, url_TKLLPG_1, refresh_interval)
```

But now, even a simple **driver.get(url)** doesn't work anymore. The page load for like 1 second and it automatically return back to **data:,** url. No matter how much I tried to get the above url, the page keep returning back to **data:,** url. The weird thing is that it only happens on that specifc website, as my code for other website still working as intended, and I still access that site normally, just not when I use selenium. Am I doing something wrong, or did that website know something about me using selenium?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX17f.png)

I tried random Agent User, added relevant chrome_options. I even tried a normal driver.get(url) without any chrome options, but the website keep return to **data:,** url after driver.get(url)

Comment: Show us the call to `open_and_refresh_websiteVL()`, and the values of all arguments being passed.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you for replying, I edited the post to add how I call the function `open_and_refresh_websiteVL()`

Comment: You have not shown the value of `website_url` in that call.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry for any confusion here. I just edited the post. And to clear up any misunderstanding. The `d` variable is `driver`, and I get the chrome `driver` from the function `get_chrome_driver()` , and `website_url` variable is actually the first url in my post. `refresh_interval` is 2, as it means to refresh the page after 2 second

Comment: _and website_url variable is actually the first url in my post_ I don't see how that is possible, because the first variable in your post is named `url_TKLLPG_1`, but in the function call you are passing `truyenhdx_url`.

Comment: What I mean from the post is that, even a simple `driver.get(url_TKLLPG_1)` without any chrome options doesn't work as it used to be. After one second after loading the page, the browser switch its url back to `data:,` as in the picture there

Comment: @JohnGordon oh my bad again. Sorry for that